# Execute shell command in running container on GKE from Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, function, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Trying to use Google Cloud Functions to execute a shell command within a running Container on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).

Essentially looking to reproduce the functionality of 'kubectl exec -it "wordpress-cluster-xyz" -- /bin/bash', but through the Python SDK in Cloud Functions.

I've tried the below code, however get a connection refused error.

```
from kubernetes import client
from kubernetes.stream import stream
from kubernetes.client import configuration                                              


def testing(event):
    v1=client.CoreV1Api()
    exec_command = [
    '/bin/sh',
    '-c',
    'touch ~/testing']
    resp = stream(v1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,"wordpress-cluster-xyz", 'default',
              command=exec_command,
              stderr=True, stdin=False,
              stdout=True, tty=False)
    print("Response: " + resp)
```

Error I receive:

> Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for
>   termination reason. refused 
>   Details: (0) Reason: [Errno 111] Connection

Full error logs:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py",
>   line 296, in websocket_call client = WSClient(configuration,
>   get_websocket_url(url), headers, capture_all) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py",
>   line 94, in **init** self.sock.connect(url, header=header) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 223,
>   in connect options.pop('socket', None)) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 121,
>   in connect sock = _open_socket(addrinfo_list, options.sockopt,
>   options.timeout) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 201,
>   in _open_socket raise err File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 176,
>   in _open_socket sock.connect(address) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno
>   111] Connection refused During handling of the above exception,
>   another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 346, in run_http_function result =
>   _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 217, in invoke_user_function return
>   call_user_function(request_or_event) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 210, in call_user_function return
>   self._user_function(request_or_event) File "/user_code/main.py", line
>   15, in testing stdout=True, tty=False) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/stream.py",
>   line 35, in stream return func(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py",
>   line 841, in connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec (data) =
>   self.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec_with_http_info(name, namespace,
>   **kwargs) # noqa: E501 File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py",
>   line 941, in connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec_with_http_info
>   collection_formats=collection_formats) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py",
>   line 345, in call_api _preload_content, _request_timeout) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py",
>   line 176, in __call_api _request_timeout=_request_timeout) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/stream.py",
>   line 30, in _intercept_request_call return
>   ws_client.websocket_call(config, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py",
>   line 302, in websocket_call raise ApiException(status=0,
>   reason=str(e)) kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (0) Reason: [Errno
>   111] Connection refused

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you "inspect logs for termination reason"?

Comment: Yes, they're not very useful. The reason given is basically as per above.

Comment: You have gotten "Connection refused" error, check if the service file used during deployment of CF has permissions to access k8s. It might be permission issue.